# How do I find this probability,given the following joint distribution?

Tags: probability

$X$ and $Y$ are jointly distributed random variables having the pdf

$f(x,y) = x+y, $if  $0<x<1,0<y<1,$

$\            $$0,$ otherwise.

I have to find $P(X+Y>0.5)$

Given the constraints, I solved to get the ranges of $x$ and $y$ as follows:
$0<y<0.5$ and $0.5-y<x<0.5$. (Is this correct?)
Then I solved the probability by double integrating the function $f(x,y)$ over this range, with respect to $x$ first and then with respect to $y$. 
I got the answer as $\frac{1}{12}$. But this is incorrect,according to the key. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are they uniformly distributed?

Comment: No,nothing was specified like that. X and Y are just continuous, and are jointly distributed - that’s the only information given.

Comment: I would try to find $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ by integrating the pdf from $(0,1)$. You can use this formula $f_{X+Y}(a)=\int\limits_{0}^{2}f_X(0.5-y)f_Y(y)dy$ to find out the probability that $X+Y\le 0.5$.

Comment: @PythonSage $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Comment: @NCh They don't need to be independent I believe. In fact, joint variable distribution will not be independent I guess. We can still find marginal distribution right? If I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: @PythonSage In order to multiply pdf's r.v.'s need to be independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given the constraints, I solved to get the ranges of $x$ and $y$ as
>   follows: $0<y<0.5$ and $0.5-y<x<0.5$. (Is this correct?)

Almost. It is $0<y<0.5$ and $0<x<0.5-y$. This is $P(X+Y<0.5)$. Then you have to subtract this probability from 1. The integral is

$$P(X+Y<0.5)=\int\limits_0^{0.5} \int\limits_0^{0.5-y} x+y \, dx \, dy$$

The inner integral:

$$\int\limits_0^{0.5-y} x+y \, dx =\left[\frac12x^2+yx \right]_0^{0.5-y}=\frac12\cdot (0.5-y)^2+0.5y-y^2=\frac18-\frac{y}2+\frac{y^2}2+0.5y-y^2$$

$=\frac18-\frac{y^2}2$

Now the outer integral

$$\int\limits_0^{0.5} \frac18-\frac{y^2}2\, dy=...=\frac1{24}$$

Finally we have $P(X+Y>0.5)=1-P(X+Y<0.5)$

Comment: I’m a bit confused here because I found out that range for the condition X+Y>1/2.  When I’m finding the reverse probability and I have X+Y<1/2, the upper limit for X is clearly Y-1/2,I can see that. And for Y,the upper limit is 1/2-min{X} = 1/2 - 0 = 1/2. Is this how you found it out? (The rest of the method is clear to me,thanks.)

Comment: @user733666 The upper limit for x is $\frac12-y$. Just a typo? But the rest of your comment is right. This was my method as well.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that typo. Okay,great. Thanks,it’s fully clear now.

Comment: @user733666 You´re welcome.

Comment: @callculus Does your first "Yes" really means "No"?

Comment: @NCh  Yeah. Good catch. That is what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 2):

When you integrate over $0<y<0.5$ and $0.5−y<x<0.5$, you integrates over the small triangle with vertices $(0.5, 0)$, $(0.5,0.5)$ and $(0, 0.5)$. And you need to integrate over all the unit square except triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(0.5, 0)$, and $(0, 0.5)$.

It is convinient to find the probability of the opposite event: 
$$
\mathbb P(X+Y\leq 0.5) = \int_0^{0.5} \left(\int_0^{0.5-y}f(x,y)\, dx \right)dy = \frac{1}{24}.
$$
And then find $\mathbb P(X+Y >0.5)$ from this value.

Comment: Could you further elaborate on why finding the reverse probability is more easier? I’m unable to visualise properly the first part of your answer,I’m sorry. :/

Comment: Draw a square $0 < x< 1$, $0<y<1$. Draw the line $y=0.5-x$. Region above the line is $x+y>0.5$. Region below is $x+y\leq 0.5$. Which region is simpler?

Comment: Got it. Thanks a ton. I feel dumb now. But I’ve got it.